# How to change admin password for WSO2 APIM-3.2.0 and IS-5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 APIM Manager-3.2.0 for API publishing and
Integrated WSO2 Identity server-5.10.0 with APIM as a Key Manager.

Have changed the default admin password using IS management console and I am able to login to IS management console using new password, **However I am unable to login to APIM publisher and devportal using new password** and getting Internal Server error while logging.

Comment: Have you shared the database between IS and APIM?

Comment: @Pubci thankyou somuch for your response, yes , we are using MYSQL database and it is shared between IS and APIM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following below links resolved the above issue:

**Changing admin password for IS-5.10.0:**
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#changing-the-super-admin-password

**Changing admin password for APIM-3.2.0:**
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#change-the-super-admin-credentials